# Loop through JSON file python

Tags: python

In JSON data file, I'd like to obtain the first elements in the object list.
So, John, Sam, and James in this case.

I can get first element like this below, but how do I loop through the first objects in that list without specifically replacing below values like 0,1,2?

```
data[0]["name"][0]
data[1]["name"][0]
data[2]["name"][0]
data[3]["name"][0]
...
```

code

```
with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
##prints list
print data[0]["name"]
##print first element in that list
print data[0]["name"][0]
```

json

```
[{
       "name":[ "John", "Sam", "Rick"]
   },
   {
       "name":[ "Sam", "Paul", "Like"]
   },
{
       "name":[ "James", "Saul", "Jack"]
   }
]
```

Comment: What did you try so far? If you have not googled "for loop in python" so far, I strongly recommend you to do so.

Answer (score 3):

```
def get_first_name_from_each_dict(data_list):
    return [d['name'][0] for d in data]
```

```
print(get_first_name_from_each_dict([
    {
        "name": ["John", "Sam", "Rick"]
    },
    {
        "name": ["Sam", "Paul", "Like"]
    },
    {
        "name": ["James", "Saul", "Jack"]
    }
]))
```

```
['John', 'Sam', 'James']
```

Comment: By the way, if you wish to obtain _unique_ names that appear first in each list, change the output list to a set.

Answer (score 1):

```
names_res = map(lambda i: i['name'][0], data)
```

It outputs a lazy 'generator' which is memory efficient, which is much better than consuming all data

```
print(list(names_res))

>> ['John', 'Sam', 'James']
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the types of loops in Python to fully understand what this code is doing

You can use a `for` loop to iterate through every object in the `data` list

```
names = []
for name_list in data:
    names.append(name_list["name"][0])
```

Or you can do it all in one line with list comprehension

```
names = [name_list["name"][0] for name_list in data]
```